# How send user to other page view in SwiftUI with if else statement

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to send my users to the sign-up page in my app but I am having a hard time.
Instead of

```
else {
            Text("Hello")
```

I want it to go to page/view in my app. Here is an example below

`else { go to page LoginUIView as an example`

Here is the current code

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
@State private var onboadDone = false
var data = OnboardDataModel.data

var body: some View {
    Group {
        if !onboardDone {
            OnboardViewPure(data: data, doneFunction: {
                /// Update your state here
                self.onboardDone = true
                print("done onboarding")
            })
        } else {
            Text("Hello")
            
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: when and how do you want to move to sign-up page? After button click or after some exact time ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please add your code with formated. And you have declare `onboadDone` varible and use `onboardDone` in condition. so please first make it the same.
Final Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var onboardDone = false
    var data = OnboardDataModel.data
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !onboardDone {
                OnboardViewPure(data: data, doneFunction: {
                    /// Update your state here
                    self.onboardDone = true
                    print("done onboarding")
                })
            } else {
                Text("Hello")
                //Show login view
                //LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do I show the LoginUIView page instead of Hello after the onboarding is done? So where it said  Text("Hello"), I want to instead take the user to another page.

Comment: Why you use Group? For the login view, replace the  Text("Hello")  with your login view like LoginView().